# required is not working for the text field

Tags: javascript, html

`required` is working only for the `if` statment, although I have finished the `endif`, but at the same time I am not sure that this is how it should be done the `endif`.

Now the `required` is working only for the `if` stament not for the whole text field, how it can work both for if-else statement and also for the whole text field.

Does someone know how to solve this problem.

```
 <input  type="text" name="name" value="search name" onfocus="if (this.value == 'search name') {this.value = '';} endif;" required>
```

If I just write like so for text field, it works perfectly:

```
<input  type="text" name="name" required>
```

But I need to add a value before it click the text field, that's why I added:

```
value="search name" onfocus="if (this.value == 'search name') {this.value = '';} endif;"
```

Can someone knows how to fix this problem!

Comment: Why don't you just use a placeholder instead of value ??

Comment: That's [tag:javascript], not [tag:php]. Also [tag:javascript] doesn't have `endif`.

Comment: @Xavjer yes, you are right i should have use placeholder :) thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <input type="text" name="name" onclick="(this.value != null) ? this.value : ' ' " required placeholder="search here" />
```

Comment: Don't use search name because if the value is not search name it will always return false

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer and suggestion, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Don't compare the value of your input from search name because if you do, when you search a name it will still be false.

Comment: yes, i get it that now, thank you again for explaining it to me :)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `placeholder` attribute:

```
<input  type="text" name="name" placeholder = "search name" required>
```